# Addition in awk failing

Tags: shell, math, awk

I am using following code snippet where I export the shell variables in awk as follows:

```
  half_buffer1=$((start_buffer/2))
  half_buffer2=$((end_buffer/2))
  echo $line | awk -v left="$half_buffer1" -v right="$half_buffer2" 'BEGIN {print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
```

However for the variable 'right' in awk at times the $3 variable is being subtracted from instead of adding the 'right' variable to $3.

Comment: show sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the following provides the "wrong" answers:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | awk -v left=10 -v right=20 'BEGIN {print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
        -10     20
```

To get the right answers, remove `BEGIN`:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | awk -v left=10 -v right=20 '{print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
1       -8      23      4       5
```

The problem is that the `BEGIN` block is executed **before** any input is read.  Consequently, the variables `$1`, `$2`, etc., do not yet have useful values.

If `BEGIN` is removed, the code is executed on each line read.  This gives you the answers that you want.

#### Examples

Using real input lines from the comments:

```
$ echo ID1 14389398 14389507 109 + ABC 608 831 | awk -v left=10 -v right=20 '{print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
ID1     14389388        14389527        109     +       ABC     608     831

$ echo  ID1 14390340 14390409 69 + ABC 831 32 –  | awk -v left=10 -v right=20 '{print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
ID1     14390330        14390429        69      +       ABC     831     32
```

Also, this shell script:

```
start_buffer=10
end_buffer=100
half_buffer1=$((start_buffer/2))
half_buffer2=$((end_buffer/2))
echo  ID1 14390340 14390409 69 + ABC 831 32 –  | awk -v left="$half_buffer1" -v right="$half_buffer2" '{print $1"\t"$2-left"\t"$3+right"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}'
```

produces this output:

```
ID1     14390335        14390459        69      +       ABC     831     32
```

Comment: I am sorry that line was accurate this one is giving me wrong answer : After running command :ID1 14389925 14390425 69 + ABC  831 32  ; Original line : ID1 14390340 14390409 69 + ABC 831 32

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni I just updated the answer with what I get from that input line.

Comment: I am using the command as exactly specified and yet it is giving me the wrong answer, is it because of the assignment of $half_buffer1 and $half_buffer2 variables to right and left awk variables?

Comment: Possibly.  Try `echo awk -v left="$half_buffer1" -v right="$half_buffer2"` and let's see what it shows.

Comment: I did the following:       start_buffer=10;  end_buffer=100 ;  half_buffer1=$((start_buffer/2)) ; half_buffer2=$((end_buffer/2)) ; echo awk -v left="$half_buffer1" -v right="$half_buffer2" , I get : awk -v left=5 -v right=50

Comment: I tried that as a shell script and you can see the results that I get in the updated answer.  What OS are you using?  (I ask because the awk on Sun/Solaris is known for being buggy.)